# Нужно получить координаты мышки при клике по фрейму. Java

Tags: java

Есть класс `mouseClickForTable` с перегруженным методом

```
Public class mouseClickForTable implements MouseListener {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public mouseClickForTable(){
        x = y = 0;
    }

    public int getXX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getYY(){
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Это в мейне:

```
frame.addMouseListener(new mouseClickForTable());
```

Как мне получить координаты точек в мейн, при клике по frame?
Он в консоль их выводит, событие `mouseClicked` работает, но вытащить их не получается.

Comment: получить куда? небольшое замечание - классы принято называть с Большой буквы и везде использовать CamelCase.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, спасибо за замечание, только недавно в JAVA пошел)

Comment: что вы планируете делать с этими координатами? как использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Создай объект класса MouseClickForTable и передай его в качестве аргумента

```
frame.addMouseListener(your_object);
```

и вызывай соответствующие методы

```
your_object.getXX();
```

Comment: я так понял, эти координаты один раз только передаются в мейн, а как в мейне проверять событие клика, если оно произошло, то вытаскивать новые координаты?

`mouseClickForTable m = new mouseClickForTable();


        frame.addMouseListener(m);
        
        int x = m.getXX();
        int y = m.getYY();

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);`

Answer (score 0):

В мейне предполложим есть метод, использующий координаты

```
public static useCoords(int coordX, int coordY){

}
```

в mouseClickForTable вызываем етот метод:

```
@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();

        MainFrame.useCoords(x, y);

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
```